# How does this JavaScript function work

Tags: javascript

I'm reading some tutorials on W3School.

I right-clicked and view page source and found this function within the source code:

```
function submitTryit() {
    var t = document.getElementById("textareaCode").value;
    t = t.replace(/=/gi, "w3equalsign");
    var pos = t.search(/script/i)
    while (pos > 0) {
        t = t.substring(0, pos) + "w3" + t.substr(pos,3)
             + "w3" + t.substr(pos+3,3) + "tag" + t.substr(pos+6);
        pos = t.search(/script/i);
    }

    document.getElementById("code").value = t;
    document.getElementById("tryitform").action = "tryit_view.asp?x=" + Math.random();
    validateForm();
    document.getElementById("tryitform").submit();
}

function validateForm() {
    var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
    if (code.length > 5000) {
        document.getElementById("code").value = "<h1>Error</h1>";
    }
}
```

What does this do?

```
var pos = t.search(/script/i)
```

and what does this do?

```
t = t.substring(0, pos) + "w3" + t.substr(pos,3)
     + "w3" + t.substr(pos+3,3) + "tag" + t.substr(pos+6);
```

Comment: I suggest you search for and take a look at official documentation *already available* on the web: [String.prototype.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) and [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: are you learning javascript with help of W3School, or trying to implement something functioning the same as the W3School? if you are just learning js, then there is no need to view the source code of w3school website.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax

```
/script/i
```

creates a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) that matches the characters "script" in a case-insensitive manner (that it, it will match `"script"`, `"Script"`, `"SCRIPT"`, etc.). This line:

```
var pos=t.search(/script/i)
```

sets `pos` to the position of the first occurrence in `t` of the characters "script" regardless of case. (It will set `pos` to -1 if `t` does not contain a matching character sequence.)

The other line you asked about:

```
t=t.substring(0,pos) + "w3" + t.substr(pos,3) + "w3" + t.substr(pos+3,3) + "tag" + t.substr(pos+6);
```

replaces the "script" sequence that was found with the characters "w3scrw3ipttag" (while preserving the case of "script" in the original string).

Please don't ask me why they are doing this. Also, please don't try learning JavaScript by reading site source code. (At least until you have mastered the basics, and even then.... A lot of it is quite horrible.) Instead, spend your time reading some of the very good [tutorial information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/learn/javascript) that's available.

Answer (score 0):

```
pos=t.search(/script/i)
```

It seems that `t` is the value of a text area, that is to say, whatever the user has entered in said text area.

```
t.search(/script/)
```

This uses a regular expression to search for the the characters "script" within whatever the user has entered.

```
t.search(/script/i)
```

The `i` flag makes it case insensitive (so that it'll match "Script", "SCRIPT" etc).

```
var pos=t.search(/script/i);
```

This assigns the position of a first match to the variable `pos`

```
alert("StackOverflow Rocks!".search(/rock/i));
```

would alert "14", as this is the position of the first match.

If no match is found, then `search` returns -1